# What does the bracket in `movl (%eax), %eax` mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att, addressing-mode

I have googled enough but could not figure out what the bracket `()` means. Also, I see some syntax as `movl 8(%ebp), %eax`

Could some someone suggest me some good reference? I have not been able to find any in the top 20 results from Google.

Comment: Possibly hampering the search is the fact that AT&T and Intel have their own versions of assembly--this is AT&T syntax.

Comment: I had figured that out, but I was unable to find a decent reference that explained all the GNU AS syntax.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`%eax` is register EAX; `(%eax)` is the memory location whose address is contained in the register EAX; `8(%eax)` is the memory location whose address is the value of EAX plus 8.

Comment: Plus 8 what? 8 bytes?

Comment: Not 8 bytes, simply 8, the number 8. Let's say %eax contains the value 0x01, (%eax) means the memory location at index 0x01, so 8(%eax) means memory location at index 0x09.

Answer (score 11):

http://web.archive.org/web/20080215230650/http://sig9.com/articles/att-syntax is quick introduction into Unix (AT&T) asm syntax. Googled by `at&t asm syntax`.

The post is "AT&T Assembly Syntax" by vivek (http://web.archive.org/web/20080228052132/http://sig9.com/blog/vivek), 2003-09-01. There is main info about AT&T from it:

> For example, the general format of a basic data movement instruction in INTEL-syntax is,
>
> ```
> mnemonic    destination, source
> ```
>
> whereas, in the case of AT&T, the general format is
>
> ```
> mnemonic    source, destination
> ```

(I remember this order as calling AT&T asm as genuine Unix asm, so it is *right* one, and it flows data to the right; while Intel syntax was based on some incorrect masms doc, which are clearly not right for Unix world, they are *left* and data flows to the left)

> All register names of the IA-32 architecture must be prefixed by a '%' sign, eg. %al,%bx, %ds, %cr0 etc.
>
> All literal values must be prefixed by a '$' sign. For example,
>
> ```
> mov $100,   %bx
> mov $A, %al
> ```
>
> The first instruction moves the the value 100 into the register AX and the second one moves the numerical value of the ascii A into the AL register.
>
> In the AT&T Syntax, memory is referenced in the following way,
>
> ```
> segment-override:signed-offset(base,index,scale)
> ```
>
> parts of which can be omitted depending on the address you want.> %es:100(%eax,%ebx,2)
>
> Please note that the offsets and the scale should not be prefixed by '$'. A few more examples with their equivalent NASM-syntax, should make things clearer,
>
> ```
> GAS memory operand      NASM memory operand
> ------------------      -------------------
>
> 100                     [100]
> %es:100                 [es:100]
> (%eax)                  [eax]
> (%eax,%ebx)             [eax+ebx]
> (%ecx,%ebx,2)           [ecx+ebx*2]
> (,%ebx,2)               [ebx*2]
> -10(%eax)               [eax-10]
> %ds:-10(%ebp)           [ds:ebp-10]
> Example instructions,
> mov %ax,    100
> mov %eax,   -100(%eax)
> ```
>
> Operand Sizes. At times, especially when moving literal values to memory, it becomes neccessary to specify the size-of-transfer or the operand-size. For example the instruction,
>
> ```
> mov    $10,    100
> ```
>
> only specfies that the value 10 is to be moved to the memory offset 100, but not the transfer size. In NASM this is done by adding the casting keyword byte/word/dword etc. to any of the operands. In AT&T syntax, this is done by adding a suffix - b/w/l - to the instruction. For example,
>
> ```
> movb    $10,    %es:(%eax)
> ```
>
> moves a byte value 10 to the memory location [ea:eax], whereas,
>
> ```
> movl    $10,    %es:(%eax)
> ```
>
> moves a long value (dword) 10 to the same place.
>
> The jmp, call, ret, etc., instructions transfer the control from one part of a program to another. They can be classified as control transfers to the same code segment (near) or to different code segments (far). The possible types of branch addressing are - relative offset (label), register, memory operand, and segment-offset pointers.
>
> Relative offsets, are specified using labels, as shown below.
>
> ```
> label1:
>     .
>     .
>   jmp   label1
> ```
>
> Branch addressing using registers or memory operands must be prefixed by a '*'. To specify a "far" control tranfers, a 'l' must be prefixed, as in 'ljmp', 'lcall', etc. For example,
>
> ```
> GAS syntax        NASM syntax
> ==========        ===========
>
> jmp   *100        jmp  near [100]
> call  *100        call near [100]
> jmp   *%eax       jmp  near eax
> jmp   *%ecx       call near ecx
> jmp   *(%eax)     jmp  near [eax]
> call  *(%ebx)     call near [ebx]
> ljmp  *100        jmp  far  [100]
> lcall *100        call far  [100]
> ljmp  *(%eax)     jmp  far  [eax]
> lcall *(%ebx)     call far  [ebx]
> ret               retn
> lret              retf
> lret $0x100       retf 0x100
> ```
>
> Segment-offset pointers are specified using the following format:
>
> ```
> jmp    $segment, $offset
> ```

He also recommends gnu as (gas) docs: http://web.archive.org/web/20080313132324/http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/as/index.html

Comment: "The first instruction moves the the value 100 into the register AX"..........you mean BX.

Comment: I did not mean anything, I just quote the linked page with some comments.  vivek (Vivek Mohan), 2003-09-01 (http://web.archive.org/web/20080228052132/http://sig9.com/blog/vivek) did mean that in http://web.archive.org/web/20080215230650/http://sig9.com/articles/att-syntax. Some of his projects (http://udis86.sourceforge.net/) are authored and maintained by Vivek Thampi (github.com/vmt).

Answer (score 4):

They're *move* instructions, moving data from one place to another - in these cases, from memory into a register:

```
register_eax = *(unsigned long *)register_eax;
```

Your other example is something like:

```
register_eax = *(unsigned long *)(register_ebp + 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

LaC is right.
Symbol () means the address of the register.
And %eax is the value of that address.
so 'movl 8(%ebp), %eax' means set %eax with the address of the %ebp.

Comment: LEA sets EAX = the *address*.  MOV sets EAX = the value *from memory at that address*.  Your re-phrasing of the existing answer isn't adding anything new, and is actually less clear because you're mis-using "address" to mean "memory at that address", which is the opposite of what "address" normally means.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30290496)